# Ember-formly Addon's component isn't found

Tags: ember.js

I'm am trying to get the [ember-formly addon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-formly) working like the readme.md file for that addon shows. So, I:

1. Ran `ember install ember-formly`
2. Dumped the [example form data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-formly#routecomponentcontroller) `Model()` and `fields` into my application/controller.js file
3. Put the [basic template data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-formly#basic-template) into a blank templates/application.hbs file:

   {{ember-formly fields=fields model=model}}

And that gives me this error when I load it up in my browser:

> Assertion Failed: Could not find component named "custom-fields/html-input" (no component or template with that name was found)

Being rather new to Ember.js I'm sure I'm missing something simple... Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Please share application.hbs code.

Comment: thanks, application.hbs code added

Comment: Have you checked out the other options? That addon seems to be pre-release. https://emberobserver.com/?query=forms  --  after looking at the ember-formly page, I'm also confused at its example directions, "Route/Component/Controller:"  - maybe you can ask the author and then help clarify the docs.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `custom-fields/html-input` instead use `ember-formly-fields/html-input`. 
This addon is providing only one component `ember-formly-fields/html-input` and for other components you need to have implemented it.(ie., for date-picker you need to use any other addon which provides date-picker component and you can use that here)